# ASP NET attribute routing array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

So I am using attribute routing for my controller like this:

```
    [Route("last/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUpdateLast([FromUri] int id) { 
        return Ok();
    }
```

Now I want to convert it to accept an array of integers, in the controller parameter I just switch to `[FromUri] int id[]` with no problems, however, how do I switch the route attribute `[Route("last/{id:int}")]` to make it accept an array of integers?

Comment: Correct syntax for an array is `int[] ids`, is that what you meant? And routing via array I've always seen done via string param and the parsing the values from the string into an array, although often it's a problem of the wrong setup. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your were almoust there, there is no way of doing what you want using the route, so use as a query string :

[image]

[image]