# Bind multiple values from the query string to an array parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created the following ActionMethod as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719274/asp-net-attribute-routing-array):

```
[Route("[action]")]
public IActionResult Orders([FromRoute] int[] filterby)
{
    ICollection<Order> all;
    if(filterby.Length != 0)
    {
        all = _db.Orders.Where(s => filterby.Contains((int)s.Status)).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        all = _db.Orders.ToList();
    }

    return View(all);
}
```

When the request URI is something like:

`http://localhost:5000/admin/orders?filterby=0&filterby=1`

The `filterby` parameter is always an array of 0 length. What can't I get it working?

Comment: Try changing to [FromUri] as suggested by your link.

Comment: @Zaki, [FromUri] doesn't exist.

Comment: make sure System.Web.Http is imported https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Zaki, There is no System.Web, it's ASP.NET CORE!

Comment: @VSG24 If you have enough rep, add the answer as an actual answer, rather than editing your question. That will show other users that the question has been answered, and will be easier to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ASP.NET core you have two choices:

1. (Recommended) Use the new attribute `[FromQuery]`
2. Import the package `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` and use the old `[FromUri]`